# Regex find words between tags in a text where tags are repeated

Tags: java, regex, string, replace, tags

I am using Matcher.

Given this string:

```
Hi, I am a [l=BANANA] and I am [l=YELLOW]
```

I tried with

```
\\[l=(.+)\]\
```

But in this case Matcher.group(1) is

```
l=BANANA] and I am [l=YELLOW
```

Instead I'd like Matcher.group(1) to be

```
BANANA
```

and Matcher.group(2) to be

```
YELLOW
```

Anyway... What I am trying to do is to eliminate [l=] tags, so if there is a method to transform

```
Hi, I am a [l=BANANA] and I am [l=YELLOW]
```

to

```
Hi, I am a BANANA and I am YELLOW
```

it would be great!

Comment: Check [`\[l=(\w+)\]`](https://regex101.com/r/aX0fO0/3)

Comment: and this str.replaceAll("(\\[l=|\\])", "")

Answer (score 2):

This happens because `.+` is *greedy*, which means that it would attempt to match as many characters as possible.

You should either make it *reluctant*, i.e. `.+?`, meaning that it would attempt to match as little characters as possible.

Better yet, replace dot `.` with "anything except `]`" expression, i.e.

```
"\\[l=([^\\]]+)\\]"
```

This is a common way of matching a string up to a delimiter using regex.

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/WmaYre)

Comment: Instead of `[^\\]`, `\w+` or `[A-Z]+` can also be used in this case. `\[l=(\w+)\]`

Comment: @Tushar That's entirely possible. However, since OP does not say that he wants only word characters after `l=`, a situation when someone enters `[l=YELLOW SUBMARINE]` could be possible. The most general approach would be to match text up to the closing bracket, even though it has a space in it.

Comment: It's strange, with your regex this error is given: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unmatched closing ')' near index 12

Comment: @user2468425 I moved the slash, and added a Java demo.